# MySQL construct query with JOIN + GROUP + foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a salaries tables as shown in graphic below. Employee number `emp_no` is a foreign key.  The follow query works fine:

```
SELECT 
emp_no, ANY_VALUE(salary)
 FROM salaries 
 GROUP by salaries.emp_no 
 LIMIT 0, 500
```

But if I try to ORDER BY salary DESC it throws the following error:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'employees.salaries.salary'
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is there a way to construct this query so it on shows me the highest `salary` v each `emp_no`?  I am trying to constuct a proper query - not a workaround for ***sql_mode=only_full_group_by***

[image]

Comment: Is `emp_no` is the primary key of the `salaries` table?

Comment: It is foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an alias:

```
SELECT emp_no, ANY_VALUE(salary) as any_salary
FROM salaries 
GROUP by salaries.emp_no 
ORDER BY any_salary DESC
LIMIT 0, 500
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to construct this query so it on shows me the highest salary v each emp_no?

You seem to be looking for aggregate function `max()` rather than `any_value()`:

```
select emp_no, max(salary) as max_salary
from salaries 
group by emp_no 
order by max_salary desc
limit 0, 500
```

`any_value()`, as its name indicates, gives you an arbitraty value out of those available in the group (ie records having the same `emp_no`). On the other hand, `max()` returns the greatest available value in each group.